# localStorage get empty when i refresh the page

Tags: javascript

localStorage gets empty when i refresh the page.

What i have done in code is :-
1)I have store the authToken in localStorage 
2)I have store isReloaded value in sessionStorage to check if page is new open or is postback

If browser tab is first time open then increment the browser tab count value in tabCount localStorage and if browser is reloaded then no value should be added in tabCount and if i close all the tabs without logout of page all localStorage should get clear.

Purpose of code to achieve : -

1) page should clear the localStorage values if all the browser tabs are closed without logout of the page.
2) instance of page should open in multiple tabs

```
$(window).load(function () {


if(!sessionStorage.getItem('isReloaded'))
{
    //first time call

   if(localStorage.getItem('tabCount') == null || localStorage.getItem('tabCount') == undefined)
   {
       var tabCount = 1;
       localStorage.setItem('tabCount',tabCount.toString());    
   }
   else
   {
      var tabCount = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('tabCount'));
      tabCount += 1;
      localStorage.setItem('tabCount',tabCount.toString()); 
   } 


}
else
{
    // postback code here
    console.log('in postback...')
}

 sessionStorage.setItem('isReloaded',true);

});

$(window).unload(function(){

     var tabCount = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('tabCount'));
     if(tabCount > 0)
     {
        tabCount -= 1;
        if(tabCount == 0)
        {
            //RemoveLocalStorage('tabCount,authToken,userId,userName,userFullName,caseNo,consumerName, consumerFirstName, consumerLastName, consumerList, userData,timeStamp');
           localStorage.setItem('tabCount',tabCount.toString());                   
           localStorage.clear();
        }
        else
        {
          localStorage.setItem('tabCount',tabCount.toString()); 
        }                   
     }

});
```

Comment: `unload` ? Why ? Use `sessionStorage` instead in such cases..

Comment: Unload is used to decrement tabCount value as soon as I close the browser tab.I have used sessionStorage to check if page is refresh or new page.